# Date(timeIntervalSince1970:) returns 2 different results

Tags: ios, swift, date, epoch

I am getting some results from a weather API and one of that is date in epoch time stamp.

I found that converting with `Date(timeIntervalSince1970:)` I get the right date

I am using the specific number --> `1501452000` and I get 2 results on Playground

1) `Jul 31,2017,12:00AM`. -- when --> `let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1501452000)`

2) `2017-07-30 22:00:00 +0000` when --> `print(date)`

API results are :
`"time_epoch": 1501452000,
 "time": "2017-07-30 23:00",`

By checking the rest of my results they are matching with the rest of the API results....... but when I convert `1501452000` -> to date I don't get the correct Hour 23:00 but 22:00 !

Any idea what is happening ?
is it wrong the API( I don't think so  ) or the way I am converting it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timeIntervalSince1970` initializer sets up the time in the UTC timezone, while your API might be sending `date`s in GMT. When you are using `print(data)`, you have different results, because if you are not using a `DateFormatter` to generate the `String` format of the `Date` object, it uses your devices current settings when formatting the `Date` object.

A `Date` object represents an absolute point in time, but when you are printing it with a `DateFormatter`, it gets converted into a location/time zone specific, relative representation. You just have to set up your `DateFormatter` to match the time zone settings of your API and you will see the dates correctly printed.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. it worked. As you said the API timestamp was in GMT so I had to make a Dateformatter and it worked.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider upvoting it.

Comment: I tried David but since I am a new user here I have less than 15 reputation !!!!! so I will when I will have 15. Damn it's embarrassing hehehe !!! Have a great one

Comment: Since I am trying to get the time correct wouldn't be best to convert the time to local when I am parsing the API Data ? and then I will have to check only the local time and the saved data ? 

If this is best I guess this happens with timeZone = TimeZone.current ?

Comment: It depends on what you need the time for from you API. If it represents local time, then yes, use `dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current`.

Comment: It represents local time so I did that and it seams that it works so far ok! Thanks again David

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens on daylight saving times. Is your country changing daylight saving on this exact date?

Answer (score 0):

1. `let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1501452000)` in Playgrounds should give you the time in your system's timezone when you see it on the right hand side.
2. When you print it and see `2017-07-30 22:00:00 +0000`- this is the same timestamp in GMT

Is the API showing a particular time zone? It looks like GMT+1

Comment: The only thing I can get from the API is "Date": "Sun, 30 Jul 2017 21:38:24 GMT"

Comment: In your question you said:  `API results are : "time_epoch": 1501452000,
 "time": "2017-07-30 23:00" `